# WPF recompute based when collection changes

Tags: c#, wpf

Essentially I have a collection of answers in the form of `QuestionID, StudentName, Answer`. I'll like to show the count of the number of answers that have been submitted for the current question. Seems like I could simply do it with a notify that the collection has changed event, but I'm failing to show the updated count on the view. Any thoughts on what's wrong? Or any better ways of doing this?

#### Edited to include my BaseViewModel

```
 public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
    
public class AnswersViewModel : BaseViewModel{        
private static ObservableCollection<Answer> _answers;

    public AnswersViewModel()
    {           
        _answers = GetAnswers();

    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Answer> Answers { get {return _answers;} }

    public ObservableCollection<Answer> GetAnswers()
    {
        if (_answers == null)
        {
            _answers = new ObservableCollection<Answer>();
            _answers.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Answers_CollectionChanged);
        }
       
        return _answers;
    }

    void Answers_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Fired!!!!!!!"); /* Yes, it's fired*/
        OnPropertyChanged("NumAnswers");
    }

    public int NumAnswers
    {
        get
        {   
            /*THIS IS NOT BEING FIRED!*/
            int questionId = QuizViewModel.GetQuestionID();
            int numAns = (from ans in _answers where ans.QuestionID == questionId select ans).Count();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("numAns: " + numAns); 
            return numAns;
        }
       
    }
}
```

ViewModel in the data context:

```
public class CompositeViewModel
{
    public AnswersViewModel answersVM { get; set; }
    //...other view models
    public CompositeViewModel()
    {
        this.answersVM = new AnswersViewModel();
      //... other view models
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DockPanel >
        <DockPanel.DataContext>
            <viewmodel:CompositeViewModel/>
        </DockPanel.DataContext>
        ....
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=answersVM.NumAnswers, Mode=Default,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=answersVM.Answers.Count, Mode=Default,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/> <!--This works as expected-->
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Note that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Text Bindings is pointless, as the Bindings never update their sources. Setting `Mode=Default` also doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Does the AnswersViewModel class implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface? In the sample code you have posted it doesn't.

Comment: `public class AnswersViewModel { ... }` seems to indicate that AnswersViewModel does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @mm8 yes it does. I have a BaseViewModel that does that.. ought to edit it into the sample.

Comment: @Clemens what do you mean by 'never update their sources'? How would I update the value on a textblock then?

Comment: UpdateSourceTrigger is for bindings with data flow from target to source, like TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings. It triggers when exactly the source gets updated. It has no effect in OneWay Bindings.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the OnPropertyChanged and make sure that the handler is not null.

Comment: @Clemens ah ok I thought it was needed to update the text for the textblock. Will try without.

Comment: Also drop Mode=Default.